# コメントしたユーザーの名前を表示させる

Tags: php, laravel

コメントを投稿したユーザーの名前を表示させたいと思っています。
コメントは表示できますが、投稿者の名前が表示することができません。
migration fileのメソッドや型を変えてみたり
コメント機能に関する記事やリレーションに関しての記事を調べたのですがわかりませんでした。

#### CommentsController.php

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\CommentRequest;
use App\Comment; 
use Auth; 

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(CommentRequest $request)
    {
        $comment  = new Comment;
        $comment->comment = $request->comment;
        $comment->user_id = Auth::id();
        $comment->name = "";
        $comment->post_id = $request->post_id;
        $comment->save();
        return redirect()->route('bbs.show', [$comment['post_id']])->with('commentstatus','コメントを投稿しました');
    }
```

#### Comment.php

```php
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

#### comments_table.php

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('is_deleted', 4)->default('0');
            $table->integer('post_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('comment');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

#### show.blade.php

```
              @forelse($post->comments as $comment)
                    <div class="border-top p-4">
                        <time class="text-secondary">
                            {{ $comment->user->name}} //名前を表示させる箇所
                            {{ optional ($comment->created_at)->format('Y.m.d H:i') }} / 
                            {{ optional ($comment)->id }}
                        </time>
```

Answer (score 0):

comments テーブルに user_id カラムが必要です。

Comment: 外部キーを使い、            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');を追加しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決されたということでしょうか？よかったです^ ^

Comment: はい、無事にmigrateできました^^ 
また別のエラーが発生したので、戦っております！